# How to assign cell arrays to field in nested structure?

Tags: arrays, matlab, assign, cell-array

Suppose I have a cell array that I want to assign to a nested field.

```matlab
myArray = {{ 1     2     3     4     5}; 
           { 7     8     9     10    11    12    13}}
```

I want the endresult to be something like:

```matlab
myStruct(1).field = { 1     2     3     4     5}
myStruct(2).field = { 7     8     9     10    11    12    13}
```

Without actually having to access each individual field as I do in the above example. Also, I want to avoid using a for-loop.

Finally, how do we perform the inverse (again without accessing individual fields or using a for-loop): extract `myArray` from the `myStruct` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two very specific MATLAB functions for this: [`cell2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) and [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html).

For the first conversion, you just have to pay attention to use the correct axis by choosing the correct `dim` parameter. You have a `2 x 1` cell array here, so it's `dim = 2`.

For the second conversion, you can just use `struct2cell` as is.

Here's the complete code:

```matlab
myArray = {{ 1     2     3     4     5}; 
           { 7     8     9     10    11    12    13}}

myStruct = cell2struct(myArray, 'field', 2);
myStruct(1).field
myStruct(2).field

myArrayAgain = struct2cell(myStruct).'
```

The output then looks like this (shortened):

```
  myArray =
  {
    [1,1] =
    {
      [1,1] =  1
      [1,2] =  2
      [...]
    }

    [2,1] =
    {
      [1,1] =  7
      [1,2] =  8
      [...]
    }

  }

  ans =
  {
    [1,1] =  1
    [1,2] =  2
    [...]
  }

  ans =
  {
    [1,1] =  7
    [1,2] =  8
    [...]
  }

  myArrayAgain =
  {
    [1,1] =
    {
      [1,1] =  1
      [1,2] =  2
      [...]
    }

    [2,1] =
    {
      [1,1] =  7
      [1,2] =  8
      [...]
    }

  }
```

Hope that helps!